# Clone Polymer element with value changed listeners

Tags: dom, polymer, listener, clone

Is it in Polymer possible to clone an element so that the listeners are still listening to value changes?

Let's say I want to copy these two elements in `#copyDiv` which fire eachother true a value change.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="copyDiv">
      <project-picker id="projectPicker" project="{{projectObject}}" on-value-changed="projectChanged"></project-picker>
      <deliverable-picker projectId="{{projectId}}"></deliverable-picker>
 </div>
```

**projectChanged listener:**

```
projectChanged: function(newD, oldD) {
            [...some functionality]

            this.projectId = this.$.projectPicker.project.projectCode;
        },
```

When the projectId is changed the `deliverable-picker` will be fired to execute some functionalities. This is working as it should. However, when I try to copy both elements, the `projectChanged` is not called when a project is picked from the cloned element.

**UPDATE**

Below you can find a screenshot of my module I'm trying to copy. When a project is selected a list of deliverables is populated. After the users clicks on a item, the deliverable is added to the summary on the right. When I click on the button "add another project" the whole element (red border) must be copied over and append below. 
[image]

Code for clone the dom node:

```
addAnotherProject: function() {
            var newProject = this.$.projectdelivcombi.cloneNode(true);
            for (var i in this.$.projectdelivcombi.properties) {
                newProject[i] = this.$.projectdelivcombi[i];
            }
            this.$.projectdelivcombiContainer.append(newProject);
        },
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: What do you mean by "copying"/"cloning" the elements?

Comment: I've added some detailed information about what I'm trying to do. Hope this will clarify my problem?

Comment: Ok, I see. The group of things you're cloning should instead be inside a `dom-repeat` template, which is bound to an array. `addAnotherProject()` should be adding new project-model instances to that array.